# Capture key input on select (dropdown list) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to capture the input on a dropdown in JavaScript when it is focused, but it appears to not throw events.

Without using a third party library, is there anyway to capture this input?

```
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/m4tndtu4/11/
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but to target an ID in jQuery you do `$("#sel1")`, and you don't have any inputs ?

Answer (score 0):

you don't want a third party library, but tagged your question to jquery.
you also use jquery code inside your jsfiddle, and mix it with native js...

so i assume, that you would at least want to use jquery.

i edited your fiddle the following: http://jsfiddle.net/m4tndtu4/14/
i just deleted everything you wrote, and just entered one 'on' handler:

```
$("#sel1").on("keyup",function(){ //this captures selection changes 
    $("#output").css("background-color", "yellow").text($('#sel1 option:selected').text()); // change the css of output and set the text to the value of the selected option

var enteredSearchSequence = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    $("#input").css("background-color", "yellow").text(enteredSearchSequence);
});
```

currently, it shows only the last pressed key - and also don't work if <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> was pressed... but i guess, you can figure out, how to concat the keypress or even delete it, because it's treated as a new search.

btw. given that, you may want to take a look at angularjs or any other mvc - a list and a searchbox is quite easy with those frameworks!

Comment: Hi Errand, what I am trying to achieve is reading the key that was pressed so I can create a string of characters as the user searches the drop down list.

Comment: hi errand, this is pretty interesting, but I still don't see the output string being printed in that fiddle. I have tried breakpointing it and it doesn't seem to fire events once you focus the ddl.

Comment: It is important that it captures the input whilst the list of options is visible.